# Discord.py Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'

Tags: python, json, api, request, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def akatsuki(ctx, *, arg):
  akatsukirequest = requests.get(f"https://akatsuki.pw/api/v1/users/whatid?name={arg}").json()
  ok = akatsukirequest.json()['id']
  avatarcontent = f"https://a.akatsuki.pw/{ok}.png"
  await ctx.send(avatarcontent)
```

The code of mine is above but it won't print out the `id` section of this url `https://akatsuki.pw/api/v1/users/whatid?name=Cover` (cover is the arg I used) I don't understand this error (Im new to python and discord.py) error = `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'`

Comment: You wrote `.json()` twice.

Comment: Yea just noticed that.. woops...